# Example of sending claim to azure-ad-b2c policy from JS single page application

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-b2c, claims, azure-ad-msal

I'm using msal js library to redirect SPA to b2c policy.

I can't find an example of sending some custom claim to the b2c policy (like extension_Brand) from javascript application.

What I have found is .NET example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/d62c3f9e573ac8b5a9adc1565c6254f632e2a531/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipMusicWebApplication/Startup.cs#L108
But it uses .NET library.

Which JS library can send claim to the b2c policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no JS examples that I know of.

You **can** use [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) to send claims to B2C via the `extraQueryParameters` arg on [`loginPop`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/docs/classes/_useragentapplication_.useragentapplication.html#loginpopup), [`loginRedirect`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/docs/classes/_useragentapplication_.useragentapplication.html#loginredirect), etc.

Make an ajax call to the server to get a JWT and then pass along that JWT to B2C.

---

The claims are sent to B2C in [that example here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/d62c3f9e573ac8b5a9adc1565c6254f632e2a531/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipMusicWebApplication/Startup.cs#L249):

```cs
context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("client_assertion_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer");
context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("client_assertion", selfIssuedToken);
```

---

**Sample JS code**

The server-side example is just making an HTTP request which means you can do the same thing in JavaScript:

```
var client_assertion_type = encodeURIComponent("urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer");

var jwtQueryParams = "client_assertion_type=" + client_assertion_type + "&client_assertion=" + jwt;

msalApp.loginRedirect(myScopes, jwtQueryParams);
```

Comment: my server is node.js server (not .NET server), so same problem to generate JWT as on client. How to generate JWT in JavaScript?

Comment: It needs to be a server side operation.  This lib should do the trick: [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken).  See `jwt.sign(payload, secretOrPrivateKey, [options, callback])` @EdIlyin

Comment: could you, please, point to an explanation, why this should be server side operation? as this this makes one more round trip to the server.

Comment: b/c you need a `secretOrPrivateKey` which can't be protected if it is client side @EdIlyin