# Azure B2C Claims Based Authentication and Custom Claims

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

How does one implement user groups to protect the APIs using .net core 2.0 and Azure AD B2C?

---

Most of my functions are available for anyone to use, but there are a handful that are for administrators only (e.g. delete account, list all users, etc.).

In Azure one can set up a bunch of custom claims, but the user seems to have permission to edit these claims.

So, for example, I could set up an attribute which is 'Group' and set the value to 'User' or 'Administrator', but it appears to me the user could edit this attribute, thus making the whole scheme worthless.

How?

Comment: "but the user seems to have permission to edit these claims" how so?

Comment: The built-in attributes are editable by the user.  I am assuming that the custom attributes are editable as well.  If this isn't the case, then how would you set an attribute, such as 'Group' to be something like 'User' or 'Administrator'?

Comment: @DonaldAirey How did you implemented Role based authorization or in this scenario custom attribute at first place. I am stuck right now at this step. Could you please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

[Custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr) are **not** editable by the user unless they are exposed in a B2C policy (like a sign-up or edit policy)

You can set custom attributes through the [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

or

You can set custom attributes by sending a JWT to B2C with [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom).  One example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519812/example-of-sending-claim-to-azure-ad-b2c-policy-from-js-single-page-application).